# Explanation of the results of Warburg's Flashing Light experiment?

Tags: plant-physiology, photosynthesis

Between 1919 and 1920† Warburg obtained a higher rate of photosynthesis in *Chlorella*, exposed to rapid alternating periods of light and darkness, than when exposed to constant illumination.  I would expect the opposite — that continuous illumination would generate more ATP and $\ce{NADPH}+ \ce{H+}$ in the light reaction, and thus give a higher rate of photosynthesis. In the light of what we now know about photosynthesis, is there any obvious explanation for Warburg’s results?

†Cited by [Emerson, Robert and Arnold, William (1932)](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/4429/)

Comment: Can you pls put a link to his paper?

Comment: I cannot comment so I write here. Besides details that I let to people with better knowledge than me, it seems you compare or "equate" amount of product and rate. That is not correct. Think of a sprinter (that actually stop, breath and eventually restart) and a marathon runner. Who is going faster and who is covering the longer distance? Indeed I suspect that a kind of fatigue is at play, like inhibition, saturation of some path. However this latter is just me speculating. I wanted to point out the difference above. It might help.

Comment: Your justification was indeed a help.  I read this logic somewhere, but want to know precisely what the inhibitory factor is. Besides it may seem that I'm confusing rate and yield, due to my last line, but actually I'm talking about rate and not yield..

Comment: I have taken the liberty to gut this question of the references to a possible effect of the light on the 'dark' reactions of photosynthesis as the poster provided no reason or logic to make such a connection and there is no reason to make such a connection. Warburg was not in a position to deduce anything much from the original experiment, but I think it is still of interest (5 votes) to ask if his observations can be rationalized in terms of today's knowledge of photosynthesis. So I have recast it with that single focus. There seems to be literature out there discussing it.